# Can we play .swf file in android VideoView?

Tags: android, android-videoview, splash-screen

I have splash videos, *.swf* files I want to run in `VideoView` instead of running in `WebView`. Is it possible to play *.swf* in `VideoView` android, if possible please provide the solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.

A SWF file is short for Shockwave Flash.  It is a compiled runtime Flash file and requires a plugin or supported library set.

It is not a video file.
If it plays on the Android at all, it would be because you somehow found a Flash plugin that would work on your system.

What you CAN do, however is convert the file to an MP4 that CAN be played as you intend.  There are online services for this.
But many don't support audio.  And many of the free ones won't do anything longer than 2 minutes or so.

Comment: Thanks, and one more question can we implement adobe flashplayer in android? @durbnpoisn

Comment: No.  There are 3rd party methods.  There are even tutorials that show you how to do it.  But it is not recommend or secure.  More importantly, you won't be able to release anything through Google Play that way.
If you own those SWF files, you should be able to produce them in another format.  If you don't own them, you probably shouldn't be using them anyway.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to play .swf in VideoView android

No. That is not a [supported media format](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html).

Comment: Thanks, and one more question can we implement adobe flashplayer in android? @CommonsWare

Comment: @Naveen: Adobe abandoned Flash for Android years ago.